# Api for drawing chart in android

Tags: android

Is there any API for drawing financial chart in android?

Answer (score 14):

Or if you don't want to access the net for that, you could use a lib. for that, like this one: http://www.achartengine.org/ . It's pretty good, I've used it recently in a project.

Comment: I strongly suggest using this, as it is open source and pretty powerful. I needed a custom time chart for my sleep recording app and I only had to subclass and modify some of their source code. It worked perfectly!

Comment: I back the achartengine too.. Have recently used it in a project of mine

Comment: I suggest achartengine.

Comment: Well , when it comes to using broken graph demo , the broken line graph fails to recogise the osition of currently added dots , only a plain slang straight line is resulted

Answer (score 13):

You can call the Google Charts API with HttpPost and then create an ImageView based on the OutputStream of your request. Make sure that you use ASyncTask when calling a server

Comment: Exactly what I came here to say, upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

[Vectoroid](http://vectoroid.com) is a bit lower level vector graphics API but could be used to animate them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Zeitdata Charts](http://charts.zeitdata.com). Its free.

Answer (score 0):

We can draw Charts in Android using achart-engine 
For the Demo Please refer 
http://sudheerstech.blogspot.in/2013/10/graphs-using-achart-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Highcharts which is JavaScript API and support different charts. then you can use Web View class to show diagram in android application.