# MVC MONODROID APPLICATION

Tags: model-view-controller, xamarin.android

i am using one mvc application in vs 2008,its running fine,its having chart control.

now i am creating one monodroid application.

How to access the mvc application in monodroid apllication?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are doing or expecting without any details.

If you have an ASP.NET MVC application, your best bet is to simply point the Android browser to your running web app, let it render it, and you're done.

If you are determined to port it, you will have to rewrite most of your application.  The business logic should be reusable if you encapsulated it properly, but you will have to write a new UI layer.

Also, I do not think Android ships with a chart control, so you will have to find some sort of solution for that as well.

Comment: oh k fine.then we r using chart control in application .

Comment: see [API for drawing chart on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891141/api-for-drawing-chart-in-android)